# Error in gitweb converting big svn reposity

Tags: git, svn, gitweb

I have a big svn repository with big files. I'm converting it to git. But I have this error in Apache log:

> "fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory"

I use:

> git version 1.7.2.5
> gitweb version 1.7.2.5

git is compiled with NO_CURL=1 NO_MMAP=1

I install git and gitweb using this guide: https://github.com/tmacam/private-git-on-dreamhost

And execute in server:

> git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
>
> git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
>
> git config --global pack.threads "1"
>
> git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"

And when I create server-repository I use:

> git config pack.windowMemory "100m"
>
> git config pack.SizeLimit "100m"
>
> git config pack.threads "1"
>
> git config pack.packSizeLimit "100m"

In my computer, I use this convert script:

```
$1=~/git-repo
$2=file:///home/user/svn/data/Repo
$3=http://mygit.server.com/repo.git

rm -Rf $1
mkdir $1
cd $1
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/svn2git $2 --rootistrunk --verbose

rm -Rf ~/temp   
git svn clone $2 --no-metadata -A ~/authors.txt ~/temp   
cd ~/temp
git svn show-ignore >> $1/.gitignore
rm -Rf ~/temp
cd $1

echo "Add remote"
cd $1
/usr/bin/git remote add origin $3

echo "Add git ignore"
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore.'

echo "Repack"
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"

git config pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config pack.threads "1"
git config pack.packSizeLimit "100m"

git repack -a -d 
git gc

echo "Up server"
cd $1
/usr/bin/git push origin master
```

Can you help me?

Comment: much related, maybe this can help you, in case you don't have an answer yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293304/274502