# Tortoisegit showing errors on "Clone" and "Pull"

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When trying to clone from any repository, I am getting this error:

```
POST git-upload-pack (300 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 7450, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4062/4062), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (7450/7450), 20.57 MiB | 188.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3264/3264), done.
remote: Total 7450 (delta 3264), reused 7186 (delta 3000)
Checking connectivity... fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
Unexpected end of command stream

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (154285 ms @ 17-10-2013 AM 11:57:14)
```

Please provide me a way out, if possible using TortoiseGit.

Comment: It is an out of memory error like http://stackoverflow.com/a/18516065/6309? Does it persists after a reboot? (http://i.qkme.me/3534gf.jpg)

Comment: Yes it persists after reboot.

Comment: Did you try raising `http.postBuffer`? As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309.

Comment: Yes, I raised the http.postBuffer too, but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a combination of:

- using the [latest TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Download?tm=2),
- using the [latest msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) (Git For Windows)

The [issue 1887](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1887) (August 2013) mentions:

> But I'm quite sure that this isn't a TortoiseGit issue.
>
> > We are experiencing some sort of hang-ups in TortoiseGit commands - The GUI dialog stays open, and the `git.exe` process is still running, but nothing happens. It seems like Tortoise is stuck on something.
>
> If a git process is still running, TGit is waiting for it to exit.

Now, if the same clone does work through a git bash (`git clone`), then:

> For other hang-ups:
> Please try our latest preview release and open a new issue if you experience it again. Thank you.