# Out of memory on git status

Tags: git

I'm managing an 1and1 shared server, and I using git to update it. I save the actual status in a brach named master_1437985331, use git checkout master to change to my "production" branch and finally do `git pull origin master` to try to retrieve the changes. When I do this, I recived a fatal error that says:

> fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 117502943 bytes)

I try to do this: [Git on Windows, "Out of memory - malloc failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed)

The question is that the mmap error still raising in every git operation:

```
(uiserver):uXXXXXXX:~/path > git status
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

Who I can recover git from this error? Of course, try to use `git checkout  master_1437985331` don't work and raise the same mmap error.

Thanks.

Comment: `git` is trying (but failing) to allocate 117MB (approx). I'd try raising the limits beyond the 128MB in the linked answer. However, it sounds to me like there is a *HUGE* file in `git` (or more than one), which is not what `git` is designed for. Look at `git annex`.

Comment: Thank's I find an image that have 113MB, and I delete It from my repo because I have no interest on trackhuge files. Despite this, I still traped on a mmap error on my server and I can't do git pull or git status

Comment: If you just `git rm` the file, that won't delete it from your repo. It will still be there (in previous revisions). Here's how you really remove stuff from your repo (admittedly for a different reason): https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/