# fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed in github from ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, github

I'm trying to push code to github repo from my ubuntu server. But i continuously getting following error.

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 318168757 bytes)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

I have also tried to change in config file under .git folder.

Please help me.

Comment: Looks like your server is reaching the limits of its RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `.git/config` file as below:

```
[core]
  packedGitLimit = 128m
  packedGitWindowSize = 128m

[pack]
  deltaCacheSize = 128m
  packSizeLimit = 128m
  windowMemory = 128m
```

See [Git on Windows, “Out of memory - malloc failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed)

Comment: I have already done this. but not working. i'm trying to pull/push in Ubuntu server in Amazon EC2.